# Whether CNAME is transfer to NS value by domain provider?

Tags: dns, domain, nameserver, cname

Such as, I registered a domain `example.com` on GoDaddy, the below is my `analysis` in GoDaddy:

```
Host     Type      Line       Analysis

@        CNAME     default    23he.16cdn.com.
@        NS        default    ns1.dnspod.com.
@        NS        default    ns1.dnspod.com.
www      CNAME     default    23he.16cdn.com.
```

I have a question, whether GoDaddy delivery the CNAME `@` and `www` to `ns1.dnspod.com.`? 
then in my local PC I `nslookup example.com`, then get `23he.16cdn.com.` yet?

Comment: There can not be a CNAME at apex `@` because there can not be any other record at a given label if there is a CNAME one and the opposite.

Comment: Can you explain more, I don't understand you.